# DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: ipython, cython

I know that this question has been posted multiple times. And I have done my research but still was left clueless. So please bear with me but I wanted to see if someone can offer more direct help,

I am using the latest Python xy distribution

https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/

I launched an ipython session and tried to write a simple fibonacci function, after doing load_ext cythonmagic. But ran into the above error. I also set the env. variable VS90COMNTOOLS to equal %VS100COMNTOOLS%, as some posts suggested. That did not fix it, what else can I do to fix the error?

Thanks

Comment: For compiling Python extensions, you typically have to use the version of VS that Python itself was compiled with. For Python 2.7, that's generally VS 2008 (i.e. 9.0). I doubt that just setting a `VS90*` environment variable would be enough.